# Exposed Spotify/Docker port is gone after Minio is Injected

Tags: docker, minio, spotify-docker-client

In the implementation of a Spotify docker-client library for a container, we set the ports like this:  `.withPorts((5432, Some(4444)))`

The container is created with the right port bindings and everything works fine.

The problem arises when the dependency

```
"io.minio" %   "minio"  % "4.0.0",
```

(object storage server to mock AWS s3
https://docs.minio.io/)

is added in the project.

While the dependency is not interfering with the previously mentioned container, the exposed port is not set anymore (see screenshot).

[image]

Has anyone faced a similar issue in the past?